# LSTM Network not learning from sequences. Underfiting or Overfitting using Keras, TF backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am working in a problem with sequences of 4 characters. I have around 18.000 sequences in the training set. Working with Keras+TensorFlow backend. The total number of possible characters to predict is 52.

When I use a network like you see below in "**Network A**" with around 490K parameters to learn, the network tremendously overfit and the validation loss increases like crazy even in 300 epochs. Either way, the validation accuracy does not go up to 20%.

When I use "**Network B**" below, with around 8K parameters to learn, the network does not seems to learn. Accuracy does not go over 40% even in 3000 epochs for the training data and around 10% for validation set..

I have tried lots of configurations in the middle without any real success.

**Do you have any recommendation?**

Both cases using the following config:

```
rms = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.01, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=rms,  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

---

**Network A**

```
Shape of input matrix:
    4 1
Shape of Output:
    57
```

---

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 4, 256)            264192    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 4, 256)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 4, 128)            197120    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 4, 128)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 32)                20608     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               4224      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 57)                7353      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, 57)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 493,497
Trainable params: 493,497
Non-trainable params: 0
```

---

**"Network B"**

```
Shape of input matrix:
4 1
Shape of Output:
57
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 4, 32)             4352      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 4, 32)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_7 (LSTM)                (None, 16)                3136      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 16)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 57)                969       
_________________________________________________________________
activation_2 (Activation)    (None, 57)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 8,457
Trainable params: 8,457
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your input shape is "4x1" and you feed that directly that to your LSTM, what is the format of your input ? Because here it seems that at each timestep (for each character) you have a dimension of 1 (so maybe you just passed an int ?).

As you said you are dealing with sequence of 4 characters, you have to treat them as **categorical** variables and encode them in a proper way.

You could for example **one-hot** encode them, or **embed** them using an `EmbeddingLayer` to a certain dimension.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The input sequences are encoded with a custom dict (letter to numbers) and normalized, the output predicted value is using np.utilstocategorical like: # normalize input ninput = ninput / float(vocab) #Preparare Output for Neural Network, noutput = np_utils.to_categorical(noutput) An example (before np.utils) of the sequence: Example of sequence created: [38, 33, 18, 13] ->--next value: --> 2

Comment: Do you feed directly something like [38,33,18,13] as input of your LSTM ?

Comment: The network is fed with that [38,33,18,13] normalized with ninput = ninput / float(vocab). ninput contains all the input sequences

Comment: But it's a sequence of characters, it's not the proper way to treat them. It's not the right preprocessing for a sequence of characters, because each character is a categorical variable, here you are treating them as numerical data , but you can't say that for example character 'a' is twice character 'b'.

Comment: You can one-hot encod them , having for each character a vector (of size vocab) full of 0 and a 1 at the position of the character , and your input will be '4 x vocab'. Or you can remove the normalization part of your code , and add an 'EmbeddingLayer' that will embed each character of the sequence (you can have a look at the documentation of 'EmbeddingLayer' of Keras).

Comment: Hey abcdaire, thanks again. No, there is no such math in the representation, It is a simple char to number with this code: notedict = dict((note, number) for number, note in enumerate(allnotes)) , where allnotes brings all the notes in characters like: B3,G2,A1...